# Can't get a cronjob to run a script that installs a service which requires root

Tags: cron, scripting, installation, automated-install

I need to run, on Ubuntu 18.04, via cron a script, `myscript.sh` that contains, among other things, installation instruction for another script, `pluckeye-linux-0.99.40.installer` and I'm running into a tedious error:

The script in question is the installer for [Pluckeye](https://www.pluckeye.net/) a kind of parental control app. This needs to be run as root. Inside of `myscript.sh` I have placed

```
cd "/path/to/pluckeye/"
./pluckeye-linux-0.99.40.installer
```

- When I run `sudo crontab -e` and place there

  `* 20 * * * "/path/to/myscript.sh"`

  then Pluckeye's installer returns a cryptic error (I'm redirecting the outputs of what cron execute to a file, so that I can see what went wrong):

  `0b8e:24: ca151e1e WARNING 32512
  0b8e:33: ca151e1e WARNING 0x30b8e019
  0b8e:42: ca151e1e WARNING 0x30b8e019
  0b8e:78: ca151e1e WARNING 0x30b8e019
  0c2c:14: ca151e1e WARNING 0x30b8e019
  0b4c:20: ca151e1e WARNING 0x30b8e019
  0c70:48: ca151e1e WARNING 0x30b8e019
  FAILED TO INSTALL: 6400`
- But when I run the installer normally in my shell with `sudo` (otherwise it will immediately return and error

  `I need to be invoked by root`
  `FAILED TO INSTALL: 11520`

  ) it works without any problems.

---

I assume this comes from the fact that cron uses its own, minimal environment. I have tried various things I found on the internet, like using instead of the above

`* 20 * * * . $HOME/.profile; "/path/to/myscript.sh"`

hoping to get the installer to work now, but that changes nothing. I would not like to place `sudo` inside the script, meaning

```
cd "/path/to/pluckeye/"
sudo ./pluckeye-linux-0.99.40.installer
```

as I have read that that introduces a security risk.

*What do I need to do to get Pluckeye to install itself via cron?*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

maybe you would do this:

1. using crontab -e

```
* 20 * * * sh /path/to/myscript.sh
```

2. using /etc/crontab

```
* 20 * * * root cd /path/to/pluckeye/ && sh ./pluckeye-linux-0.99.40.installer
```